# How to implement 2D Simplex Noise/ 2D Perlin Noise ( C++11)

Tags: c++, c++11, terrain, perlin-noise, simplex-noise

My problem is I dont know how to insert the simplex noise/perlin noise values to my world generator to produce a better looking landscape, is there anyone can show simple code showing how to implement it.

BTW, im new at programming, so any answers will be appreciated and it will greatly helps me.

Heres the code:

noise.h

```
#pragma once

class PerlinNoise
{
public:

  // Constructor
    PerlinNoise();
    PerlinNoise(double _persistence, double _frequency, double _amplitude, int _octaves, int _randomseed);

  // Get Height
    double GetHeight(double x, double y) const;

  // Get
  double Persistence() const { return persistence; }
  double Frequency()   const { return frequency;   }
  double Amplitude()   const { return amplitude;   }
  int    Octaves()     const { return octaves;     }
  int    RandomSeed()  const { return randomseed;  }

  // Set
  void Set(double _persistence, double _frequency, double _amplitude, int _octaves, int _randomseed);

  void SetPersistence(double _persistence) { persistence = _persistence; }
  void SetFrequency(  double _frequency)   { frequency = _frequency;     }
  void SetAmplitude(  double _amplitude)   { amplitude = _amplitude;     }
  void SetOctaves(    int    _octaves)     { octaves = _octaves;         }
  void SetRandomSeed( int    _randomseed)  { randomseed = _randomseed;   }


    double Total(double i, double j) const;
    double GetValue(double x, double y) const;
    double Interpolate(double x, double y, double a) const;
    double Noise(int x, int y) const;

    double persistence, frequency, amplitude;
    int octaves, randomseed;
};
```

noise.cpp:

```
#include "noise.h"

PerlinNoise::PerlinNoise()
{
  persistence = 0;
  frequency = 0;
  amplitude  = 0;
  octaves = 0;
  randomseed = 0;
}

PerlinNoise::PerlinNoise(double _persistence, double _frequency, double _amplitude, int _octaves, int _randomseed)
{
  persistence = _persistence;
  frequency = _frequency;
  amplitude  = _amplitude;
  octaves = _octaves;
  randomseed = 2 + _randomseed * _randomseed;
}

void PerlinNoise::Set(double _persistence, double _frequency, double _amplitude, int _octaves, int _randomseed)
{
  persistence = _persistence;
  frequency = _frequency;
  amplitude  = _amplitude;
  octaves = _octaves;
  randomseed = 2 + _randomseed * _randomseed;
}

double PerlinNoise::GetHeight(double x, double y) const
{
  return amplitude * Total(x, y);
}

double PerlinNoise::Total(double i, double j) const
{
    //properties of one octave (changing each loop)
    double t = 0.0f;
    double _amplitude = 1;
    double freq = frequency;

    for(int k = 0; k < octaves; k++)
    {
        t += GetValue(j * freq + randomseed, i * freq + randomseed) * _amplitude;
        _amplitude *= persistence;
        freq *= 2;
    }

    return t;
}

double PerlinNoise::GetValue(double x, double y) const
{
    int Xint = (int)x;
    int Yint = (int)y;
    double Xfrac = x - Xint;
    double Yfrac = y - Yint;

  //noise values
  double n01 = Noise(Xint-1, Yint-1);
  double n02 = Noise(Xint+1, Yint-1);
  double n03 = Noise(Xint-1, Yint+1);
  double n04 = Noise(Xint+1, Yint+1);
  double n05 = Noise(Xint-1, Yint);
  double n06 = Noise(Xint+1, Yint);
  double n07 = Noise(Xint, Yint-1);
  double n08 = Noise(Xint, Yint+1);
  double n09 = Noise(Xint, Yint);

  double n12 = Noise(Xint+2, Yint-1);
  double n14 = Noise(Xint+2, Yint+1);
  double n16 = Noise(Xint+2, Yint);

  double n23 = Noise(Xint-1, Yint+2);
  double n24 = Noise(Xint+1, Yint+2);
  double n28 = Noise(Xint, Yint+2);

  double n34 = Noise(Xint+2, Yint+2);

    //find the noise values of the four corners
    double x0y0 = 0.0625*(n01+n02+n03+n04) + 0.125*(n05+n06+n07+n08) + 0.25*(n09);
    double x1y0 = 0.0625*(n07+n12+n08+n14) + 0.125*(n09+n16+n02+n04) + 0.25*(n06);
    double x0y1 = 0.0625*(n05+n06+n23+n24) + 0.125*(n03+n04+n09+n28) + 0.25*(n08);
    double x1y1 = 0.0625*(n09+n16+n28+n34) + 0.125*(n08+n14+n06+n24) + 0.25*(n04);

    //interpolate between those values according to the x and y fractions
    double v1 = Interpolate(x0y0, x1y0, Xfrac); //interpolate in x direction (y)
    double v2 = Interpolate(x0y1, x1y1, Xfrac); //interpolate in x direction (y+1)
    double fin = Interpolate(v1, v2, Yfrac);  //interpolate in y direction

    return fin;
}

double PerlinNoise::Interpolate(double x, double y, double a) const
{
    double negA = 1.0 - a;
  double negASqr = negA * negA;
    double fac1 = 3.0 * (negASqr) - 2.0 * (negASqr * negA);
  double aSqr = a * a;
    double fac2 = 3.0 * aSqr - 2.0 * (aSqr * a);

    return x * fac1 + y * fac2; //add the weighted factors
}

double PerlinNoise::Noise(int x, int y) const
{
    int n = x + y * 57;
    n = (n << 13) ^ n;
  int t = (n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 0x7fffffff;
    return 1.0 - double(t) * 0.931322574615478515625e-9;/// 1073741824.0);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "noise.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    PerlinNoise pn;


    srand(time(NULL)); // Random
    for(int c = 1;c<=100;c++){
        int x = rand() % 10000;
        int y = rand() & 10000;
        double t = pn.Noise(x, y);
        if(t >= -1 && t <= -0.5){ // For Soil
            cout << "=";
        }else if(t >= -0.5 && t <= 0){ // For Stone
            cout << "+";
        }else if(t >= 0 && t <= 0.5){ // For Sand
            cout << "*";
        }else if(t >= 0.5 && t <= 1){ // For Lava
            cout << "#";
        }
        if(c%10 == 0){
            cout << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3tap.jpg

But I want this kind of output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXHpc.jpg

But I want the the soil will be in the topmost layer and generate terrain.

Comment: show some code before the nazis close your question.

Comment: Instead of implementing it yourself, why not use a library such as [libnoise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: @OneOfOne sorry, im new here, but thank you

Comment: @JoachimPileborg how to use the libnoise? can you sample a code? thanks

Comment: The library have plenty of sample code (and images) on its homepage.